# How do I match this with an express.js route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-api-nodejs-client

```
/oauth2callback?code=4/SOMECODE.LOL-ISHERE
```

Hello there the above url is sent from an OAUTH request generated by the googleapis package in node.js.

I have tried so many routes but it never matches.

```
app.get('/oauth2callback?code=4/:token', routes.oauth);

app.get('/oauth2callback*/:token', routes.oauth);

app.get('/oauth2callback/:token', routes.oauth);
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only route that will match is

`app.get('/oauth2callback', routes.oauth)`

because `/oauth2callback` is the resource path. The rest of the URL string you've described is a querystring.

You can access the query parameters on the the `req` object that will be passed to `routes.ouath`. Yours will be available at `req.params.code` and will look like `4/SOMECODE.LOL-ISHERE`

Comment: Wow.. Never would have guessed that the 4 was part of a querystring.

Comment: Everything after the `?` in a URL is the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

could you test it with app.use or app.all instead please , as I can't find  any documentation whether the request send by this package would actually be a get request! These options will at least allow you to rule out such occurrences where the request is not as expecte